# Accessing the gallery images automatically uisng ionic

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, ionic2, phonegap-plugins, cordova-plugins

I m trying to build a gallery application using Ionic, For reading images  I used ImagePicker, to select images in the device. But this will prompt the user to pick images.
I m trying to access the the image files automatically without picked up by the user, Can please somebody help on this.